# how to load this jquery notification bar on page load instead of clicking the button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, notifications, popup

i need some tweaking advice since i'm not familiar with javascript and jquery. i want to add a notification on top of my page when it loads. for example when i load my home page (index.html) i want the notification to appear.

the current example only pop up the notification when i click the button. i want it to appear when i load the page. can someone help me out? im kinda interested in this notification bar.

i got it from http://tympanus.net/Development/jbar/

my current code is like this (index.html):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery Plugin jBar</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="screen"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">           
                <a id="msgup" class="button">Demo Top</a>
        </div>


    <script src="jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.bar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $("#msgup").bar({
            color            : '#1E90FF',
            background_color : '#FFFFFF',
            removebutton     : false,
            message          : 'Your profile customization has been saved!',
            time             : 4000
        });
    </script>   
    </body>
</html>
```

and the jquery.bar.js file :

```
    (function($) {

    $.fn.bar = function(options) {
        var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.bar.defaults, options);
        return this.each(function() {
            $this = $(this);
            var o = $.meta ? $.extend({}, opts, $this.data()) : opts;

            $this.click(function(e){
                if(!$('.jbar').length){
                    timeout = setTimeout('$.fn.bar.removebar()',o.time);
                    var _message_span = $(document.createElement('span')).addClass('jbar-content').html(o.message);
                    _message_span.css({"color" : o.color});
                    var _wrap_bar;
                    (o.position == 'bottom') ? 
                    _wrap_bar     = $(document.createElement('div')).addClass('jbar jbar-bottom'):
                    _wrap_bar     = $(document.createElement('div')).addClass('jbar jbar-top') ;

                    _wrap_bar.css({"background-color"   : o.background_color});
                    if(o.removebutton){
                        var _remove_cross = $(document.createElement('a')).addClass('jbar-cross');
                        _remove_cross.click(function(e){$.fn.bar.removebar();})
                    }
                    else{               
                        _wrap_bar.css({"cursor" : "pointer"});
                        _wrap_bar.click(function(e){$.fn.bar.removebar();})
                    }   
                    _wrap_bar.append(_message_span).append(_remove_cross).hide().insertBefore($('.content')).fadeIn('fast');
                }
            })


        });
    };
    var timeout;
    $.fn.bar.removebar  = function(txt) {
        if($('.jbar').length){
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            $('.jbar').fadeOut('fast',function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }   
    };
    $.fn.bar.defaults = {
        background_color    : '#FFFFFF',
        color               : '#000',
        position            : 'top',
        removebutton        : true,
        time                : 5000  
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Im certain the index.html is in need of change as to how it loads the notification. but i dont know what to edit. please help as i want to learn this.

Comment: @Dasarp im sorry but can you please elaborate on that? i really not familiar with this. very sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quick and dirty way would be to call

```
$("#msgup").click();
```

right after you do all of your

```
$("#msgup").bar({
  ...
});
```

stuff.

Comment: Thnx. i assume this is also faking a click in a page which loads  #$msgup right because it has a click event listener? however it worked.thnx.

Comment: it worked but i would like to remove the button as i dont need it..how could i accomplish this? because it's calling #msgup

Comment: @Psychocryo: Yes, it just triggers a click. As for your second question, you could set its css display property to none, e.g. `#msgup { display:none; }` in a css file. Although, now we are heading down the silly road to hackville. Maybe it would be a good idea to extract the functionality of the plugin to just get the behavior you want (i.e. show a message on load that disappears after a few seconds). It may take you a while at first to get your head around jQuery and all this stuff, but a little effort up front will save you lots of time down the road!

Comment: thnx for the advise! i will look into it.thnx again.

Answer (score 1):

I see the plugin only adds a `click` event listener. So you can fake a click in `index.html`, add this code immediately before `</head>`:

```
   <script> $(document).ready(function(){ $("#msgup").trigger('click') }); </script>
```

And it will work.

Comment: Won't work as written since he doesn't load the jQuery library in the document head, but that's an easy fix.

Comment: Yes. at first it didnt work then i load the jQuery lib first like @Cameron said and it worked!

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#msgup").bar({
        color            : '#1E90FF',
        background_color : '#FFFFFF',
        removebutton     : false,
        message          : 'Your profile customization has been saved!',
        time             : 4000
    });
});
```

Comment: thnx but where should i put this? i still need to use "#msgup"?